# sequelize query between date range (createdAt)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I wanted to query in sequelize between a range of start and end-date but it does not seem to work. I've tried using between but it does not seem to work either. What is the correct way of implementing this on sequelize ? what is wrong with the query below ? Thank you.

#My code

```
if (query && query.startDate && query.endDate) {
  query = {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.between]: [query.startDate, query.endDate],
    },
  };
}
```

#also have tried

```
if (query && query.startDate && query.endDate) {
      query = {
        [Op.and]: [
          { createdAt: { [Op.gte]: query.startDate } },
          { createdAt: { [Op.lte]: query.endDate } },
        ],
      };
    }
```

#query at the console

```
query {
  '$skip': '0',
  '$limit': '25',
  startDate: '2020-07-19',
  endDate: '2020-07-20'
}
```

Comment: log your query at the console by enabling logging like this - logging: console.log, then check what issue with you query

Comment: @Mark by using this logging: console.log, you are able to see your sql query, we need to debug sql not query string

Comment: but I am using sequelize  , how am i going to log the sql ?

Comment: var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    logging: console.log
    logging: function (str) {
        // do your own logging
    }
});

Comment: this is the sql for the data when i log it .`createdAt` <= '2020-07-19 16:00:00'));

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demo code for example

```
// building query string to 
    buildQuery(query) {
        var whereClause = {                      
                          
        };
        // pms filter is necessery 
        if(query && query.pms_id) { 
            whereClause['pms_id'] = query.pms_id;
         }
        // checkin date filter
        if(query && query.start_date) {            
            const arrivalFrom = moment(query.start_date).subtract(2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            whereClause['checkin_date'] >  arrivalFrom;
        } else {
            const arrivalFrom = moment().subtract(2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            whereClause['checkin_date'] >  arrivalFrom;
        }
        // checkout date filter
        if(query && query.end_date) {            
            const arrivalFrom = moment(query.end_date).add(2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            whereClause['checkout_date'] <  arrivalFrom;
        } else {
            const arrivalFrom = moment().add(2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            whereClause['checkout_date'] <  arrivalFrom;
        }
        return whereClause;
    }
// query for getting bookings related to user
    getBookings(user_id,query="") {
        return bookingModel.findAndCountAll({
            where: this.buildQuery(query), 
            include:[
                { model:pmsModel, 
                  where: { user_id:  user_id},
                  required:false
                  },
                  {
                      model: propertyModel,
                      required:false
                  },
                  {
                    model: roomModel,
                    required:false
                }
                ],           
        });
    }
```

Comment: but that is the only query I needed